# Database that doesn't get corrupted when killed or on power loss

Tags: database

Everyone says "don't kill MySQL, don't kill MySQL ...".

But if a database gets corrupted when you kill it, how will it react to power loss?

What's a database software that doesn't get corrupted when killed or on power loss?

Comment: And that is why "real" servers use a UPS and either flip over to generator power OR monitor the UPS and when it indicates battery power only they initial a shutdown (of services or just the whole system).  As to a db, perhaps a single-file based one like sqlite hsql etc

Comment: @ivanivan Why single-file? ext3/4 with `data=journal` correctly handle multiple files; this is just about the database not interleaving transactions or leaving them half-done I guess.

Comment: Just about any database that isn't MySQL will survive a crash, a power failure, or other unexpected termination.  People say "Don't kill MySQL" because MySQL is unusually fragile in this respect.

Comment: @Mark So PostgreSQL is fine for this? I wonder why anyone uses MySQL then ...

Comment: @DepressedDaniel, MySQL is designed to be very fast for the read-mostly workloads involved in running a website.  PostgreSQL and most other databases are designed for general-purpose workloads, and are considerably slower than MySQL when used as a website backend.

Comment: @Mark: Postgres is definitely not "considerably" slower then MySQL. That is a myth that might have been true 10 years ago (and even back then for highly concurrent read/write workload Postgres was already faster)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Write-ahead log (WAL)

Any heavy-duty enterprise-quality database uses a [write-ahead log](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write-ahead_logging) to first capture incoming data. Only after the entire chunk of data (the [transaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction)) is captured is it then written to the actual database. If the computer fails, the pending transaction is rolled back with the actual database left intact. If the failure happened after the entire transaction was recorded successfully in the WAL, then upon restart, the database system can roll-forward to attempt writing the data into the actual database.

WAL has other benefits too beside data-protection. You can restore a back-up of a database and then bring it up-to-day by replaying the WAL files collected since the back-up was taken. And WAL files are the basis for replication where you maintain a second installation of your database in near real-time by forwarding a copy of the WAL files from the primary database to the secondary database.

Keep in mind that WAL is not the only aspect of protecting your data. You must also guard against memory corruption ([ECC memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECC_memory)) and storage corruption ([RAID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID), [ZFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS), etc.). And using an [uninterruptible power supply (UPS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninterruptible_power_supply) is always a good idea.

### Postgres

[image]

[Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org) is one of the leading enterprise-quality databases that [makes use of WAL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/wal-intro.html) to protect your data. Also open-source and free-of-cost – truly so on both counts, with no catches & no fine-print.

Other examples include [Microsoft SQL Server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186259(v=sql.105).aspx) and Oracle.